# How to assign null values to dynamic property type

Tags: c#, ado.net

Basically, I am in need of a converter which converts a `DataReader` object to generic type.

so when I do -

```
while(dataReader.HasRows()){
    var result= dataReader.ConvertToObject<MyModel>();
}
```

It calls an extension method of generic type -

```
public static T ConvertToObject<T>(this DbDataReader reader) where T : new()
{
    T res = new T();

    T t = new T();

    for (int inc = 0; inc < reader.FieldCount; inc++)
    {
        Type type = t.GetType();
        PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty(reader.GetName(inc));
        var value = reader.GetValue(inc);
        if (value == System.DBNull.Value)
        {
            value = null;
        }

        var targetType = IsNullableType(prop.PropertyType) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) : prop.PropertyType;

        value = Convert.ChangeType(value, targetType);

        prop.SetValue(t, value, null);
    }

    res = t;
    return res;
}

private static bool IsNullableType(Type type)
{
    return type.IsConstructedGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>));
}
```

It works fine until the the result in `datareader` is `System.DBNull` except the `System.String`

To handle null values I forcefully checked if the value is type of `System.DBNull` then assign it a C# `NULL` object.

```
if (value == System.DBNull.Value)
{
    value = null;
}
```

This however fails the conversion when the result is null for numeric type object.

So basically I am trying to do is when the result value is type - `System.Nullable[System.Decimal]`

then

```
if (value == System.DBNull.Value)
{
  value = (System.Decimal?) null;
}
```

**Or**

```
value = (System.DateTime?)null //for DateTime
value = (System.Int32?)null //for Int32
```

**What I tried to get dynamic property type**

```
if (value == System.DBNull.Value)
{
    value = (prop.PropertyType ?) null; // to get it dynamic
}
```

This didn't work. Please let me know what I have to do?

Comment: Have you tried using `default(T)`?

Comment: Have you considered using a micro-ORM like PetaPoco?

Comment: @JonSkeet, Not yet. Let me try

Comment: @mjwills, Relatively new to me. Should give it a try

Comment: @JonSkeet, Got this work using `default(T)`. Thanks

Comment: Okay, will add that as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't specify `null` as a value of type `T` because it might not be a valid value for `T`. (Think `int` etc.)

However, you can use `default(T)`, which will be the default value for `T` - the same value you'd get if you left a field of type `T` uninitialized, for example. That will be:

- For reference types, a null literal
- For nullable value types, the null value of the type
- For non-nullable value types, the "all zero" value (0 for all numeric values etc)